# simple math javascript sum all data with same variable

Tags: javascript, math

```
function mathx(n){
  var total
    for(var i = 0; i<n.length; i++){
        var sumlah = n[i] * 2;
    }
}
mathx('123')
```

I will multiply all the data in the variable sumlah. On the code snippet there are 3 numbers that will be multiplied by the number 2 if this code is executed it will produce var sumlah = 1 * 2, var sumlah = 2 * 2 and var sumlah = 3 * 3. The result of a sumlah of 2,4,6. And I want to multiply all the data sumlah. I tried using * = but failed.

Comment: Your title says you want to sum all the data, the question says you want to multiply. Which is it?

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
  function mathx(n, multiple) {
      var digits = n.split('');
      return digits.map(function (x) {
          return Number.parseInt(x) * Number.parseInt(multiple);
      }).reduce(function (x, y) {
          return x * y;
      });
  }

console.log( mathx('123', 2) )
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use map:

```
function mathx(xs) {
   return xs.map((x) => x*2);
}

mathx([1,2,3])
```

That just do the work. `map`takes a function and the result replace every value from the list.

Also, don't use a string `'123'`, use a list: `[1,2,3]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can be extra fancy by using map and reduce

```
function mathx(n) {
   return n.split('').map(Number).reduce(function(acc, val) {
      return acc + (val * 2);
  }, 0);
}

alert(mathx('123'));
```

JSFiddle: [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/04rervur/1)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will work for what you want:

```
function mathx(n) {
  var sumlah = 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
    sumlah *= n[i] * 2;
  }
  return sumlah;
}
alert(mathx('123'));
```

You had two variables that you I believe were supposed to be the same - `total` and `sumlah`.

Your biggest problem is that `sumlah` was declared inside the `for` loop. By declaring it outside of the loop, it has scope outside the loop.

You want to calculate twice the current number with `n[i] * 2`. Then, multiply it into the accumulator `sumlah` with `sumlah *= n[i] * 2;`. When you are done, return it with `return sumlah;`.

However, it is best not to use a string to store numeric data. Try an array instead: `[1, 2, 3]`. Then you can do this:

```
function mathx(n) {
  var sumlah = 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
    sumlah *= n[i] * 2;
  }
  return sumlah;
}
alert(mathx([1, 2, 3]));
```

Which is almost the same, but makes sense to other people.

Comment: If you initialize `sumlah` to zero, all the multiplications return zero. You need to initialize it to 1.

Comment: @Barmar righto. I had that as an artifact from when I thought it was sum (not product) and I had +=. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `sumlah` to `1`, then use `*=` to multiply each result into it. And you have to return the result.

```js
function mathx(n) {
  var sumlah = 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
    sumlah *= n[i] * 2;
  }
  return sumlah;
}

console.log(mathx('123'));
```